# QGIS Official Plugin Repository is available in MacOS

Tags: qgis-plugins, satellite, macos

No matter which version of QGIS I download, the status of my "plugin repositories" says "unavailbe". And I can't delete this entry as it comes with the system.

In addition, when I try to load the Google images in 'XYZ Tiles'z, it doesn't show up either, even after adding the new plugin 'QuickMapServices'y it doesn't load the Google images successfully.
I am very confused, is this a MacOS problem?

[image]

Comment: Which iOS are you using?

Comment: Are you really using QGIS 3.2 ? CF the screenshot is showing 3.2. You should first at least install 3.28, the latest LTR of QGIS. Then, it seems your QGIS can't access the internet (if QGIS can't download plugins, can't download tiles etc), so check if your organization has a proxy ?

Comment: The  version of macOS is 12.4.And I use the research institution's wifi for networking. So i don't know if my QGIS can access the internet? And do you know how to check if my organization has a proxy? Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: And i installed QGIS in  3.4 version, it didn't work either.

Comment: QGIS 3.4 (understand 3 04) is outdated as well, from 2019. Please download latest 3.28 or 3.30 https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html But this won't change the network status. Can you try from a personal wifi ?  Settings window -> Network -> Proxy

Comment: i've downloaded version 3.28, and used my personal wifi, but unfortunately, it still did't work.